# How prevent an application from running with batch?

Tags: batch

For example: I run **taskmgr.exe** and it closes.
How do I do that with *batch*?

Comment: as in a batch file or a batch job? what users are you trying to block? I assume they will be interactive?

Comment: not even gonna comment on the answer?

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think of of doing this via batch scripting would be to leave a .bat running in the background, constantly looping and checking for a specific application process image name running.

But a) I can't see why you would want to autokill a process rather than stop it from running in the first place

b) I can't see why you would want to do this with a batch script.  Batch scripts won't respond to windows events automatically to the only thing to do is to kludge together an infinitely running loop that checks if something is running.

c) Doing things in batch is like building a house of cards with a hammer and I love it, so here's an answer anyway you old person you:

```
@ECHO OFF
:loop
    set "app=TASKMGR.exe"

    ::Set Output of tasklist command to variable %TL%

    FOR /F "tokens=* USEBACKQ" %%A IN (`TASKLIST /FI "IMAGENAME EQ %app%"`) DO (SET "TL=%%A")

    ::check for "info:no( tasks are running which...)"
    ::any other output, task exists, so kill it

    IF "%TL:~0,8%" NEQ "INFO: No" (TASKKILL /FI "IMAGENAME EQ %app%")

::beware of velociraptors
goto :loop
```

Personally though, I prefer this script

```
@ECHO OFF
MODE CON: COLS=80 LINES=2
set "A=***                   "
:loop
    set "app=TASKMGR.exe"
    FOR /F "tokens=* USEBACKQ" %%A IN (`TASKLIST /FI "IMAGENAME EQ %app%"`) DO (SET "TL=%%A")
    IF "%TL:~0,8%" NEQ "INFO: No" (TASKKILL /FI "IMAGENAME EQ %app%")
    SET "A= %A:~0,15%"
    echo   (@)@):::::::D%a:~1,15%%APP%
    if "%A%" equ "             ***" set "A=***                   "
goto :loop
```

Comment: I though this would do:`@echo off :A taskkill /f /im taskmgr.exe goto :A
`

Comment: That's essentially what I did in the first script but I included an IF to check if taskmgr.exe is actually running first.  I'd recommend doing that, constantly telling your system to kill a task that doesn't exist many times per second can't be good.

Comment: @Mahammad50055 That's essentially what I did in the first script but I included an IF to check if taskmgr.exe is actually running first. I'd recommend doing that, constantly telling your system to kill a task that doesn't exist many times per second can't be good.

Comment: Also as a note, it's a bit rude to post a question on a free forum then independently find an answer, but leave your question open so no one knows you've solved your problem. You should at the very least answer your own question for future reference. And perhaps, as a courtesy, look at solutions people have spent their own time creating for free, for your benefit. Luckily I already included something for you to go ram yourself with in the second script. It's a rocketship based GUI of course. And by RAM I mean use your computer's memory to help you with your problem. (\_)\_):::::::::::::D PEACE